# Grouping prevents Virtualizing?

Tags: wpf

Is it correct, that using the grouping functionality of a ListView (through CollectionView) will prevent virtualization of the items in the ListView (.net4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of .net 4.5, this should be available:

`VirtualizatingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.isvirtualizingwhengrouping.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true.  Once you add a `GroupDescription`, the `ItemsPanel` changes to a non-virtualizing version.  If you set the panel by hand, then you also have no virtualizing unless you are using a custom panel that implements it for you.

any control derived from `ItemsControl` implements this functionality.